# Citations numbering my way

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, cross-referencing, numbering, report

I cited a datasheet in a caption of one of the figures of my report. I have added a list of figures in my document, and Latex has numbered the citations in order of appearance. Now in my first chapter (Introduction) the first citation in this appears marked as [2], which I want to be [1].

So I removed the citation from the caption, but the change is not reflected in the numbering, and its still numbered one.

How can I change this? The rest of the document is fine, because no other caption has any citation

Comment: It's going to be really hard to help you without you showing us some code.

Comment: @Teepeemm I see. But what code should I add here? I have a .bib file, and I removed the citation, but it still shows up. Which part of the code would help answer this?

Comment: Did you run `bibtex` or `biber` again after you modified the caption? Note that an alternative solution would have been to use the optional argument for caption: `\caption[this caption appears in the list of figures]{this caption appears in the main text}`. But also then you need to rerun the bibliography generation.

Comment: @Marijn I had not done that. Thanks a lot, it worked.

Comment: Good that it worked. I will vote to close as a duplicate of a more generic "how to create a bibliography" question, that might help future visitors that find the current question.